# Protected constructor - not showing with GetConstructors()

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a factory method and a protected constructor defined to take a few arguments.

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected void MyClass(int agr1, int arg2)
    {
      //set private backing fields for public readonly properties
    }

    public static MyClass From(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
          return new MyClass(arg1, arg2); 
    }
}
```

Yet when I use `typeof(MyClass).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic)` the array returned has zero items in it. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Since you are passing the `BindingFlags` yourself, you must not forget to include `BindingFlags.Instance` if necessary (which in this case, it is).

Including it will work:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
var ctors = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructors(flags);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/5szM8)**.